# Edit standalone.xml while running WildFly 8.2

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8

I have a WildFly running and an application that allow to edit database connection (ds.xml), that connection use security domain. **When WildFly stopped it's work!**

**When WildFly is running**, I can write `standalone.xml` and save it but automatically the `standalone.xml` reverts to its previous state.

**Have a way to a external app to edit the `standalone.xml` with WildFly running?**

Comment: I could mostly edit configuration file(standalone.xml) with Notepad++ when WildFly server is running. Then, I run reload command on CLI in order to take effect. Could you give more detail about case, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WildFly will rewrite the configuration if there are changes to the management model. It's advised not to directly change the XML configuration file. If you need to change a setting it's best to use CLI or the web console.

Some changes don't require a reload, some do. So in some cases you can make changes at runtime and see them immediately.

If you're editing a `*-ds.xml` file in a deployment, then that deployment will need to be redeployed.